# Problem in getting filtered results from Content Resolver (Inbox Messages) 

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get all Inbox Messages using ContentResolver based on message ids stored in another table..

I want to exclude all Inbox SMSs whose message id is not in my custom table(spam_msgids).

What i am doing is (I dont know whether this is correct or not):

```
Uri uriSms=Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, null,"_id NOT IN (SELECT msg_id FROM spam_msgids)",null,null);
```

**But its giving me an error though table is already created** ...

```
Error : 07-19 17:04:16.412: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(141): 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: spam_msgids: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM sms WHERE (type=1) AND (_id NOT IN (SELECT msg_id FROM spam_msgids)) ORDER BY date DESC
```

Can anyone please tell me where i am going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch all IDs from you database, build a comma separated string and pass it to NOT IN so that it would look like:

`Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, null,"_id NOT IN (" + stringOfCommaSeparatedStringOfIDs + ")",null,null);`

Answer (score 1):

You are querying from android internal database and surely that database doesn't include spam_msgids

Comment: What should i do then ?.. How can i move my spam_msgids to android internal database... or how can i query for my android external database >..

Comment: First retrieve the sms from android database.Then in another cursor retrieve the id from your database then from the two cursor find what you need.A bit programming..

Comment: First i did like that only.. But i was not able to filter inbox messages ?.. Any example related to it ?

Comment: @Kartik You can fetch all IDs from you database, build a comma separated string and pass it to NOT IN so that it would look like `_id NOT IN (" + stringOfCommaSeparatedStringOfIDs + ")`.

Comment: @Audrius : that worked perfectly...can you please post your comment as answer now so that i can accept your answer..